# MSAL SSO: How to obtain login account information of parent window inside child iframe?

Tags: authentication, session, iframe, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal

I am using **MSAL JS for silent authentication** in my iframe inside any web application(Yammer, Teams etc). According to documentation and various user Q&A, **we need to pass account information(name or session) to acquireTokenSilent method.** Else it will reject stating createUserLoginRequiredError.

I tried passing application scope as request but it couldn't authenticate without user interaction and hits catch block as it don't have loginHint to make SSO. **So how to get that loginhint if I got authenticated in parent window.** In ADAL, we can do it using displaycall and replacing prompt = none. How to do similar SSO in MSAL?

I tried below code,

```
const requestObj = {
            scopes: [ Appresource ]
        };
 myUserAgentApplication.acquireTokenSilent( requestObj ).then( () => {

                // Success
            } )
                .catch( ( exception ) => {

                    // Failure
                    myUserAgentApplication.loginPopup( requestObj ).then( () => {

                        // Success after interaction.
                    } )
}
```

MSAL.js:

```
UserAgentApplication.prototype.acquireTokenSilent = function (userRequest) {
        var _this = this;
        // validate the request
        var request = RequestUtils_1.RequestUtils.validateRequest(userRequest, false, this.clientId);
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            // block the request if made from the hidden iframe
            WindowUtils_1.WindowUtils.blockReloadInHiddenIframes();
            var scope = request.scopes.join(" ").toLowerCase();
            // if the developer passes an account, give that account the priority
            var account = request.account || _this.getAccount();
            // extract if there is an adalIdToken stashed in the cache
            var adalIdToken = _this.cacheStorage.getItem(Constants_1.Constants.adalIdToken);
            // if there is no account logged in and no login_hint/sid is passed in the request
            if (!account && !(request.sid || request.loginHint) && StringUtils_1.StringUtils.isEmpty(adalIdToken)) {
                _this.logger.info("User login is required");
                return reject(ClientAuthError_1.ClientAuthError.createUserLoginRequiredError());
            }
...............................
...............................
```